# Respond to key press events in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, keyboard-events

I want to respond to key presses, such as the `esc` key on macOS/OSX, and when using an external keyboard on iPad. How can I do this?

I have thought of using `@available`/`#available` with SwiftUI's [`onExitCommand`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3340135-onexitcommand), which looked very promising, but unfortunately that is only for macOS/OSX. How can I respond to key presses in SwiftUI for more than just macOS/OSX?

Comment: No universal way, so far. `UIKeyCommand` for iOS, and `NSEvent` for macOS. Following can be helpful [SwiftUI iOS - how to capture hardware key events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59798172/12299030) and [How to detect keyboard events in SwiftUI on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61155272/12299030)

Comment: @Asperi That's unfortunate. Thanks for these links, I'll get it working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update: SwiftUI 2 now has [`.keyboardShortcut(_:modifiers:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/keyboardshortcut(_:modifiers:)).

---

#### OLD ANSWER:

With thanks to [@Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) to pointing me in the right direction, I have now managed to get this working.

The solution was to use `UIKeyCommand`. Here is what I did, but you can adapt it differently depending on your situation.

I have an `@EnvironmentObject` called `AppState`, which helps me set the delegate, so they keyboard input can be different depending on the view currently showing.

```
protocol KeyInput {
    
    func onKeyPress(_ key: String)
}


class KeyInputController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {
    
    private let state: AppState
    
    init(rootView: Content, state: AppState) {
        self.state = state
        super.init(rootView: rootView)
    }
    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        true
    }
    
    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
        switch state.current {
        case .usingApp:
            return [
                UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputEscape, modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(keyPressed(_:)))
            ]
            
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func keyPressed(_ sender: UIKeyCommand) {
        guard let key = sender.input else { return }
        state.delegate?.onKeyPress(key)
    }
}
```

AppState (`@EnvironmentObject`):

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {

    var delegate: KeyInput?
    /* ... */
}
```

And the scene delegate looks something like:

```
let stateObject = AppState()
let contentView = ContentView()
    .environmentObject(stateObject)

// Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = KeyInputController(rootView: contentView, state: stateObject)

    /* ... */
}
```

This makes it really easy to now add functionality depending on the keys pressed.

Conform to `KeyInput`, e.g.:

```
struct ContentView: View, KeyInput {

    /* ... */

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world!")
            .onAppear {
                self.state.delegate = self
            }
    }
    
    func onKeyPress(_ key: String) {
        print(key)
        guard key == UIKeyCommand.inputEscape else { return }
        // esc key was pressed
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

On macOS and tvOS there is an `onExitCommand(perform:)` modifier for views.
From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3340135-onexitcommand):

> Sets up an action that triggers in response to receiving the exit command ***while the view has focus.***
>
> The user generates an exit command by pressing the Menu button on tvOS, or the escape key on macOS.

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            TextField("Top", text: .constant(""))
                .onExitCommand(perform: {
                    print("Exit from top text field")
                })
            
            TextField("Bottom", text: .constant(""))
                .onExitCommand(perform: {
                    print("Exit from bottom text field")
                })
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The above example works great on macOS as-is, however, if the TextField's are inside a ScrollView instead of a VStack, the TextField's onExitCommand actions are not performed.  Adding an onExitCommand modifier to the ScrollView will catch the escape, but not directly tell you which one (if any) had focus.

Answer (score 5):

[.keyboardShortcut(_:modifiers:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/keyboardshortcut(_:modifiers:))

ATTENTION! "modifiers" input parameter by default is not empty! So if you use this function/modifier with some key you will get unexpected result!

---

OR for other cases:

```
.onAppear() {
    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { (aEvent) -> NSEvent? in
        if aEvent.keyCode == 53 { // if esc pressed
            appDelegate.hideMainWnd()
            return nil // do not do "beep" sound
        }
            
        return aEvent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution is the .onExitCommand modifier.
As @Chuck H commented, this does not work if the text field is inside a ScrollView or like in my case, a Section.
But I discovered that just by embedding the TextField and its .onExitCommand inside a HStack or VStack, the .onExitCommand just works.

```
                    HStack { // This HStack is for .onExitCommand to work
                        TextField("Nombre del proyecto", text: $texto)
                        .onExitCommand(perform: {
                            print("Cancelando edición....")
                        })
                        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                        .lineLimit(1)
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! Saved my day, your solution works with `List` as well!! You rock!

Comment: Just wondering is there is way to detect when TextField loses focus, unfortunately @FocusedState didSet is not detecting it

Comment: `.onChange(of: isNewFolderInFocus) { newValue in }` seems to way to detect all value changes. It is useful to detect when the user taps outside the textfield