# Hosting Controller When Using iOS 14 @main

Tags: swiftui

I’m experimenting with a “pure” SwiftUI app. It doesn’t have a `SceneDelegate` so I’m unsure of where to put Hosting Controller stuff that I need for when it’ll be running on iOS.

Previously in the `SceneDelegate` I’d have code that would say something like:

```
let contentView = ContentView()
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
```

Now I just have an `@main` file with:

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

So where does the Hosting Controller stuff go (or how else can I access UIKit features that SwiftUI doesn’t have? (Specifically, I want to mess with the status bar, auto hiding the home indicator, and a few things about light/dark mode that SwiftUI’s `preferredColorScheme` doesn’t cover.)

Answer (score 18):

Here is a possible approach (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)... but if you intend to use UIKit features heavily it is better to use UIKit Life-Cycle, as it gives more flexibility to configure UIKit part.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
      Text("Demo Root Controller access")
        .withHostingWindow { window in
            if let controller = window?.rootViewController {
                // .. do something with root view controller
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func withHostingWindow(_ callback: @escaping (UIWindow?) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.background(HostingWindowFinder(callback: callback))
    }
}

struct HostingWindowFinder: UIViewRepresentable {
    var callback: (UIWindow?) -> ()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak view] in
            self.callback(view?.window)
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem. I played around with an alternative solution with zero set up, meaning it would work with SwiftUI App and Playgrounds (I even wrote a set of Playgrounds for documentation) - The package is called [SwiftUIWindowBinder](https://github.com/happycodelucky/SwiftUIWindowBinder).

Example using `WindowBinder`... See [docs](https://github.com/happycodelucky/SwiftUIWindowBinder/blob/main/README.md) for other usage, such as event view modifiers (like `onTapGesture`), or the convenience of `WindowButton`.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUIWindowBinder

struct ContentView : View {
    /// Host window state (will be bound)
    @State var window: Window?

    var body: some View {
        // Create a WindowBinder and bind it to the state property `window`
        WindowBinder(window: $window) {
          
            Text("Hello")
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    guard let window = window else {
                        return
                    }

                    print(window.description)
                }
          
        }
    }
}
```

Only caveat of the package is you cannot use a host window to construct your view. I have a whole Playground [page on this](https://github.com/happycodelucky/SwiftUIWindowBinder/blob/main/Playgrounds/WindowBinderPlayground.playground/Pages/GotchasOfWindowBinder.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift).

Answer (score 3):

@Asperi

Here is the same for macOS:

```
extension View {
    func withHostingWindow(_ callback: @escaping (NSWindow?) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.background(HostingWindowFinder(callback: callback))
    }
}

struct HostingWindowFinder: NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewType = NSView
    
    var callback: (NSWindow?) -> ()
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak view] in
            self.callback(view?.window)
        }
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

with the usage:

```
                .withHostingWindow({ window in
                    if let controller = window?.windowController {
                        controller...
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what you are looking to change, but you can do the following modifiers on `ContentView` `.statusBar(hidden: true)`. This could also be placed in parts of the app where it might make sense to hide in a specific circumstance.

This article has an great list of all the new modifiers available. https://medium.com/better-programming/swiftui-views-and-controls-the-swift-2-documentation-youve-been-waiting-for-dfa32cba24f3#6299

Answer (score 0):

As a potentially simpler approach, this solved the problem for me in iOS 15:

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .onAppear {
                if let window = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene)?.windows.first {
                    // you can now use window or window.rootViewController as needed
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in @Asperi code. It doesn't wait until window is really attached, and sometimes self.callback(view?.window) returns nil.

Here is a fix I made:

```
#if os(iOS)
private extension View {
    func withHostingWindow(_ callback: @escaping (UIWindow?) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(HostingWindowFinder(callback: callback))
    }
}

private struct HostingWindowFinder: UIViewRepresentable {
    var callback: (UIWindow?) -> Void

    func makeUIView(context _: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = HostedView()
        view.windowFinder = self
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_: UIView, context _: Context) {}

    private class HostedView: UIView {
        internal var windowFinder: HostingWindowFinder?
        override func didMoveToWindow() {
            super.didMoveToWindow()
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.windowFinder?.callback(self?.window)
            }
        }
    }
}

#elseif os(macOS)

private extension View {
    func withHostingWindow(_ callback: @escaping (NSWindow?) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(HostingWindowFinder(callback: callback))
    }
}

private struct HostingWindowFinder: NSViewRepresentable {
    var callback: (NSWindow?) -> Void

    func makeNSView(context _: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = HostedView()
        view.windowFinder = self
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_: NSView, context _: Context) {}

    private class HostedView: NSView {
        internal var windowFinder: HostingWindowFinder?
        override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
            super.viewDidMoveToWindow()
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.windowFinder?.callback(self?.window)
            }
        }
    }
}
#endif
```