# Hide Title Bar in SwiftUI App for macCatalyst

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

How can I hide the Title Bar in the new SwiftUI App Protocol?

Since the AppDelegate.swift and SceneDelegate.swift protocols are gone, I cant follow this documentation anymore:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/removing_the_title_bar_in_your_mac_app_built_with_mac_catalyst

I can't implement this code:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
            titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
            titlebar.toolbar = nil
        }
        #endif
    }
}
```

Hope it's still possible with the new AppProtocol..

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `withHostingWindow` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63276688/12299030) to find own window and then do what's needed.

Comment: @Asperi, thanks for your response, thanks to your answer I was able to hide the titlebar. I'll post the answer, but I still hope Apple adds official support soon.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how to hide the titlebar:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Example UI")
        }
        .withHostingWindow { window in
            #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
            if let titlebar = window?.windowScene?.titlebar {
                titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
                titlebar.toolbar = nil
            }
            #endif
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    fileprivate func withHostingWindow(_ callback: @escaping (UIWindow?) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.background(HostingWindowFinder(callback: callback))
    }
}

fileprivate struct HostingWindowFinder: UIViewRepresentable {
    var callback: (UIWindow?) -> ()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak view] in
            self.callback(view?.window)
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: UIKit is our everything! :D

Comment: @imike Yes, i look forward to the time where SwiftUI will have everything to :)

Comment: A better approach is to create a subclass of UIView and implement its willMove:toWindow:, call the callback there, and skip the async. This way there is no flicker and the titlebar is hidden immediately when the view appears.

Comment: I added the `if let titlebar` conditional from the `.withHostingWindow` modifier, right into my AppDelegate, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

On your Scene, set .windowStyle(_:) to HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle().

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
    }
}
```

EDIT: Ah crap. While this API is supposedly available for Mac Catalyst according to the [online documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scene/windowstyle(_:)), it looks like it’s not actually marked as such in frameworks so you can’t use it.

Comment: And how can i get to a scene?

Comment: You usually create scenes in @main, e.g. WindowGroup. So set windowStyle on WindowGroup.

Comment: i tried that, but there is no option for that.

Comment: Ah sorry, the online documentation says windowStyle(_:) is available for Mac Catalyst but that doesn’t actually seem to be true. Hopefully Apple adds it!

Comment: No problem! I hope it to, it’s a must cause it makes your app look so much better.

Comment: Works like a charm in macOS 11. Thank you